# Which module can be used to get the number of logged in users per day and supports views?

Tags: users, nodes

I need to get number of users logged in a site / per day.

For ex :

May 1 : 123 logins

May 2 : 140 logins

...

May 30 : 400 logins

I've looked into few modules like login_history and counter. Login history tracks this data, but does not support Views. Is there any module which does this out of the box ?

Thanks

Comment: check https://drupal.org/project/user_stats it have view integration support

Comment: @Bala why don't you add this as an answer?

Comment: yeah. Thanks for suggesting. This module does track login count.  But it does not track time. Schema does for tracking login count does not have timestamp column

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couple of options (haven't tested either one):

1. This sandbox project seems to track login time and provides Views integration: https://drupal.org/sandbox/AshishThakur/1614582
2. [Login History](https://drupal.org/project/login_history) also tracks login time, but does not have Views integration yet. A patch was started for this, but looks like it isn't complete: https://drupal.org/node/1402266

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module might be a valid alternative to consider? Or at least a good starting point? Refer to its [community docu](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) for some more details.

**Be aware**: I'm the new maintainer of this module, it was [unsupported until recently](https://www.drupal.org/node/2380441) ...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that might work, based on the "*Login history tracks this data, but does not support Views*":

- Find the data base table used by 'login history' for the tracking of the data.
- Use the views integration of the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module to access those data in the 'login history' table from within your custom view. Refer to the available community documentation of Forena (linked on the project homepage) for more details.

**Be aware**: I'm a co-maintainer of this module.